# SendFile Telegram Bot Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, sendmessage

Нужно написать бота, который по команде дает ссылку на скачивание файла с ПК.
К примеру у меня в файл пишутся логи, нужно чтобы в Telegram при команде */logs* давалась ссылка на скачивание этого файла.

Где есть примеры как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот [статья](https://habr.com/sandbox/111328/) на Хабре по созданию бота. Там все прописано.

Алгоритм такой - в статье написано, как сделать ответы на сообщения. Вы вместо ответов сделайте отправку файлов, используя класс File.

Если не получается сделать(у меня такое было) бота используя библиотеку из статьи выше, вы можете сделать это используя Telegram-API, как написано в статье [JavaRush](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/504-sozdanie-telegram-bota-na-java-ot-idei-do-deploja). Это более сложный способ, но он лучше.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Буду пробовать.